# Como agregar una imagen a un Notebook en Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, ipython, julia

Estoy usando la siguiente línea para agregar imágenes de internet:

```
  ! [Imagen] (http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-09/animals_hero_armadillo_0.jpg)
```

esto me ha funcionando, pero he intentado con esto:

```
  ! [Imagen] (~ / Usuarios / mi nombre / Escritorio / imagen_nombre.png)
```

para agregar imágenes de mi escritorio y no funciona,no he encontrado en ningún lugar como hacerlo.

Comment: Estuve buscando en la version en ingles de esta pagina, en los comentarios de una pregunta igual lei que la imagen debía estar en la misma carpeta en la que se guardo el notebook, lo hice y me funciono haciéndolo de las dos maneras siguientes:    `<img src="imagen.png"> ` y `![titulo](imagen.png )`

Answer (score 2):

**Tipo de celda**
La celda en la cual vas a insertar la imagen debe ser del tipo `Markdow`.

**Cambiar celda**
Para cambiar el tipo de celda te posicionas sobre la celda (se  resalta de color verde), 
y te diriges a la barra de herramientas:

`Cell` - `Cell Type` y seleccionas `Markdown` (También puede hacerse con las teclas `Esc` + `M`)

**Insertar código**
Una vez hecho esto insertas el siguiente código:

```
<img src=http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-09/animals_hero_armadillo_0.jpg>
```

Si en quieres usar una imagen local:

```
<img src="imagen.png">
```

**Ejecutar Celda**

Ejecutas la celda `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

Answer (score 0):

Copia el siguiente código en la celda en modo Markdown:

```
![Modelo_Proceso.png](attachment:Modelo_Proceso.png)
```

Answer (score -1):

Tu celda tiene que ser de tipo `Markdown` y la forma mas sencilla es ir en la parte superior izquierda y buscar **`edit`**. Allí puedes agregar una imagen.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, USERNAME. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Para futuras respuestas, te recomiendo leer [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Saludos.